# Python: Reportlab. Table special line + RC index

Tags: python

I am new in Python. I have 2 huge problem (and no google search helped me), I use reportlab and my goal is a table with 3 colum and n rows. After the first row a vertical line (thicknass an the border 1 and in the midle 4). Problem, the Styl and the RC index:
Part of the Problem:
`testtable=Table(data,style=[('LINEABOVE',(0,1),(2,1),1,colors.blue),

                                            ])`
1. How can I I draw the line over all 3 colums, in this example only 2 are working.
2. How can I define the line style.

Sorry if this is to basic, but I didn´t find a solution. 
Thanks for any help.
Overlord

Comment: Ok problem 1 is solved. I have simply restarted my system and (0,1),(-1,1) works fine. Strange bug
but the other point is still open

Comment: Bug in Python, reportlab, or your system?

Comment: Good question, I run python via pythonTex in Latex. Not all is doing well, but this "bug" is realy strange. I have the same a few minutes again. Now I have found out another solution: Copy the code in a new file, with another name and let it run. The result is, that it work. Strange

Comment: How do you view the results?

Comment: Not very perfect: I use 'code' \begin{pyconsole} 'code'
and end with 'code' end{pyconsole}'code'
The bad thing is, that I get 2 pdf back- first a pdf with the code and then the table as pdf. I put the table in my original document. Other parameters didn´t run

Answer (score 1):

In the following example the comment is from an example from the reportlab mailing list and aims to explain the meaning of all line parameters. (I don't understand where `join` could apply.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('tab-styles.pdf')

# line commands are like
# op, start, stop, weight, colour, cap, dashes, join, linecount, linespacing

styles = TableStyle([
  ('GRID', (1,1), (-2,-2), 1, colors.red, 1, None, 1),
  ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.green, None, (2,2,1)),
  ('LINEABOVE', (0,1), (2,1), 1 ,colors.blue, None, (5,3,1,3)),
  ('LINEABOVE', (0,2), (-1,2), 0.25 ,colors.blue, None, None, None, 4, 0.5),
  ('LINEABOVE', (0,3), (-1,3), 2 ,colors.blue, 1)
])

data = [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
        ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
        ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
        ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]

t = Table(data , style=styles)

story = [t]
doc.build(story)
```

Comment: Thank you. 'code'('LINEABOVE', (0,2), (-1,2), 0.25 ,colors.blue, None, None, None, 4, 0.5),'code' did not change the line thickness in that way that it is smaller at the border and the maximum of thickness is in the middle. Can this be a mistake of my system?

Comment: Another Problem:
in my original csv file are ° % [] and so on
This makes a print of my table not possible. Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks